# report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly and report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly not updated

Tags: php, database, cron

I have written code to change the sorting logic in `Toolbar.php` using `report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly`. It is working fine, actually the tables

> **report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly**

and

> **report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly**

not updated.

But the table

> **report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily**

updates daily.

When I use report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily table for sorting, the query takes much time to load.

**`Toolbar.php`**

```
$this->_collection->getSelect()
            ->joinLeft(
                array('sfoi' => $this->_collection->getResource()->getTable('sales/order_item')),
                'e.entity_id = sfoi.product_id',
                array('qty_ordered' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(sfoi.qty_ordered)'))
                )
            ->joinLeft(
                array('si' => $this->_collection->getResource()->getTable('cataloginventory_stock_item')),
                'si.product_id = e.entity_id',
                array('instock' => 'si.is_in_stock')
                 )
            ->joinLeft(
                array('search' => $this->_collection->getResource()->getTable('catalogsearch_fulltext')),
                'search.product_id = e.entity_id',
                array('search_weight' => 'search.searchindex_weight')
                )

            ->joinLeft(
                array('_table_views' => $this->_collection->getResource()->getTable('report_viewed_product_aggregated_daily')),
                '_table_views.product_id = e.entity_id',
                array('views' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(_table_views.views_num)'))
                )
            ->group('e.entity_id') 
            ->order(array('instock DESC','created_at DESC', 'minimal_price ASC','qty_ordered DESC', 'search_weight DESC','views DESC'));        
            $collection->printLogQuery(true);
```

Can anyone suggest me, how to make debug, why those tables are not updated regularly.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: I have added the code, but my question is how to debug "report_viewed_product_aggregated_monthly and report_viewed_product_aggregated_yearly not updated" issue